# find specific character in a column and merge it with other columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I have a .xlsx dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AuthorName':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.", "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
               'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry", "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology", "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology", "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"],
              'NumberOfPapers':[10, 28, 34, 56, 78, 90, 54, 54, 32, 14],
              'totalAuthorsWithinField':[5, 10, 11, 30, 56, 34, 13, 45,23, 7]})
```

[dataset looks like this though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGIZC.png)
I want to search for subject fields having “Engineer” in it. Then,
calculate the average number of papers for each engineering field. Display this table with total
authors within field information.

[my output should be this table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfWKH.png)

I tried this code but got an error

```
#add a new column that is 1 if 'Engineer' appears in the Subject Field, else 0
data['isEngineeringRelated']=data['SubjectField'].map(lambda x: 1 if 'Engineer' in x else 0)
#filter for engineering rows
engineering_data = data[data['isEngineeringRelated']==1]
#groupby the engineering fields and count the average number of papers of authors in that field
display(engineering_data.groupby('SubjectField')['NumberOfPapers'].mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` to check if the `SubjectField` is related to `Engineer`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AuthorName':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.", "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
               'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry", "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology", "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology", "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"],
              'NumberOfPapers':[10, 28, 34, 56, 78, 90, 54, 54, 32, 14],
              'totalAuthorsWithinField':[5, 10, 11, 30, 56, 34, 13, 45,23, 7]})

df['isEngineeringRelated']=df['SubjectField'].str.contains('Engineer')

engineering_data = df[df['isEngineeringRelated']==True]

engineering_data.groupby('SubjectField').agg({
                                              'NumberOfPapers':'mean'
                                          ,'totalAuthorsWithinField':'sum'
                                            }).reset_index()

                          SubjectField  NumberOfPapers  totalAuthorsWithinField
0               Biomedical Engineering            33.5                       55
1  Mechanical Engineering & Transports            90.0                       34
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I display it with 'totalAuthorsWithinField' column?

Comment: @AydaBs - Updated the answer to accomodate the change , it would be helpful if you can accept the answer as well